# Aggregate outages' duration time for every day

Tags: oracle, plsql, materialized-views

I have a table where I store information about outages of some devices. Among other information it contains `beginTime` and `endTime` which represent the beginning of outage and the end of it respectively.

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
| Id |      beginTime      |       endTime       | ... |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
| 10 | 13/01/2019 11:00:00 | 13/01/2019 15:00:00 |     |
| 20 | 13/01/2019 20:00:00 | 14/01/2019 09:00:00 |     |
| 30 | 13/01/2019 18:00:00 | 15/01/2019 10:00:00 |     |
| 40 | 16/01/2019 22:00:00 |                     |     |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
```

I want to prepare report to show sum of duration of outages for each day. Because there's millions of records in a table I don't want to calculate it every time the application loads the report and instead I would like to store it in the database. I learned about materialized views and thought it would be a good tool for this task. I could make it refresh daily at the end of the day. However, I'm struggling writing a proper SQL. Assuming today is 17-01-2019, the desired content of view is this:

```
+------------+------+
|    date    | time |
+------------+------+
| 13/01/2019 |   14 |4 hours from 1st + 4 hours from 2nd + 6 hours from 3rd
| 14/01/2019 |   33 |9 hours from 2nd + 24 hours from 3rd
| 15/01/2019 |   10 |10 hours from 3rd
| 16/01/2019 |    2 |2 hours from 4th
+------------+------+
```

So far my best attempt is

```
select to_char(nvl(endTime, current_timestamp),'YYYY-MM-DD') as date,
sum(time_diff(beginTime, nvl(endTime, current_timestamp))) as time
from ttest
group by to_char(nvl(endTime, current_timestamp),'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

where `time_diff` is calculating difference between timestamps. This is obviously wrong, as it's based on `endTime`, but I'm stuck here for now with no idea where to go.

So, is this even possible? Or should I use standard table and some PL/SQL to populate it? At this point I don't know yet what are my options considering PL/SQL (like triggering it daily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ponder Stibbons's answer I managed to find a proper select:

```
select dt, nvl(24 * sum(nvl2(endtime, least(dt + 1, endtime), dt+1) 
                  - greatest(begintime, dt)),0) duration
  from ttest t
  right join (select trunc((select min(beginTime) from ttest)) + rownum -1 dt
    from all_objects
      where rownum <= sysdate-cast((select min(beginTime) from ttest) as date)) d 
    on begintime < dt + 1 and (dt < endtime or endtime is null)
  group by dt
  order by dt
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1a4990c67d64f2df7237433922ef5c75)

I do a right join with a list of all dates from the earliest date in my table to current date and sum matching records.

Answer (score 1):

My try:

```
select dt, 24 * sum(nvl2(endtime, least(dt + 1, endtime, dt + 1), dt) 
                  - nvl2(endtime, greatest(begintime, dt), begintime)) duration
  from ttest t
  join (select trunc(nvl(endtime, sysdate)) dt from ttest) d 
    on begintime < dt + 1 and (dt < endtime or endtime is null)
  group by dt order by dt
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7b97a8eed866fe7cd271a6ad0e279a38)</sup>**

I made self-join with distinct dates, then I did summing similiar to yours. Null values in `endtime` are handled by `nvl2`, but you can change it to `case when`. Result:

```
DT            DURATION
----------- ----------
2019-01-13          14
2019-01-14          33
2019-01-15          10
2019-01-30         314
```

is as desired, except last row because calculations are based on sysdate, so now it's 314 hours (but you can change `sysdate` to any date, for instance `date '2019-01-17'` if you want to test).

---

**Edit:**

> ...in this case I need a record for 17-01 with 24 hours, another one
>   for 18-01 with 24 hours and so on.

So you need date generator:

```
select dt + level - 1 dt 
  from (select trunc(min(endtime)) dt from ttest) 
  connect by dt + level - 1 < sysdate)
```

Join it with (little modified) previous query:

```
with 
  dates as (
    select dt + level - 1 dt 
      from (select trunc(min(endtime)) dt from ttest) 
      connect by dt + level - 1 < sysdate),
  details as (
    select dt, id, begintime, endtime,
           case when endtime is null then dt + 1 else least(dt + 1, endtime) end t2,
           greatest(begintime, dt) t1
      from ttest t join dates on begintime < dt + 1 and (dt < endtime or endtime is null))
select dt, 24 * sum(t2 - t1) duration
  from details group by dt order by dt
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c0d7e8bd27674c0e5eae583c4fd7d281)</sup>**

Result:

```
DT            DURATION
----------- ----------
2019-01-13          14
2019-01-14          33
2019-01-15          10
2019-01-16           2
2019-01-17          24
2019-01-18          24
...                ...
2019-01-30          24
2019-01-31          24
19 rows selected
```

Comment: It's awesome, but in this case I need a record for 17-01 with 24 hours, another one for 18-01 with 24 hours and so on.